# Incorrectly picked post for audit on low quality queue?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

Just failed an [audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/8560348) on the "Low Quality Post" queue for an answer that looks ok and it is in no way "abusive nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable" as the audit message says. More, there's another SO question on a similar topic with an almost [identical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19183007/1974224) - spaces in project path lead to problems.

1. The failed audit message for this queue is a little bit harsh IMO for this particular post, as the post itself can at most be categorised as incorrect.
2. This post was (IMO again) incorrectly pick for audit.

Am I wrong with the above two statements?

**Edit:** This is what I currently see for the audit:
[image]
I can no longer see the answer to understand why I was wrong.

Comment: see also [There is no shame in using “Skip”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/839601)

Comment: @gnat - I use skip many times when I'm not sure what to pick for review, however this answer looked ok to me

Comment: at 20 reviews a day, one is expected to have plenty time to verify that post is indeed okay prior to clicking the button. For those who don't have time to thoroughly check, there is Skip - no shame in using it

Comment: @Cristik Cerbrus' answer is correct. The post was flagged and deleted as spam. I wouldn't worry about it too much - just chalk it up to experience and look out for links in posts in future.

Comment: @gnat - it's easy to throw stones at people, I asked the question here on meta because I no longer have access to the answer and wanted to figure out if I was wrong or not.

Comment: @JonClements - that's what I hoped to get with this question - more experience :)

Comment: I merely explained how to avoid audit failures like that. You either verify the post prior to clicking Looks OK (eg by going to link to that post), or skip if this feels too much work

Comment: @gnat - looks like we are going in circles, as I said I wasn't unsure about the choice I picked, I was unsure about if I picked the right choice or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That link is completely unrelated to the answer.
It ***is*** the very definition of spam.

Just look at the *url* the link leads to: the homepage of some company.

If the link were to lead to some kind of blog about Android studio, it might've had merit, but I can't think of a (on-topic) question for SO where some company's homepage can be the answer.

Now, since this answer was spam, it can be categorized as *"abusive, nonsense, noise, spam, blatantly off-topic **or** otherwise irredeemable"*.
As long as *at least one* of these descriptions applies to the post, the post should be removed from SO.

Sure, the message might be blunt, but it gets the message across without leaving too much room for interpretation.

Comment: Unfortunately I can no longer see the post, I only see the audit message. The answer told that the person spent half a day to figure out what's happening, and that the problem was with the space in the path. Didn't notice the link.

Comment: _"Spent a the better half of a day on this, turned out there was a space in the project folder - Android studioProjects - just renamed the folder to AndroidProjects and the issue is resolved."_, where "AndroidProjects" links to some site.

Comment: If you're reviewing "spam / low quality" answers, you should really pay attention to links... The link is the reason the answer is spam, and as such, the reason you failed the audit.

Comment: @Cerbrus - yeah, I missed the link, I read only the text and the text looked ok.